# Is there a way to downgrade .Net 7 app to .Net framework app?

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, .net-4.8

I am currently working on .Net7 application. The .Net7 application runs on win 10 and above computers. I tried it on windows-7 and does not run. I cannot upgrade the windows version because of hardware issues(Very old). So the only choice I have is to downgrade my app to .Net framework 4.x.x.
Is there a way to downgrade my app without reconstructing it again?

Comment: _"I tried it on windows-7 and does not run."_ And rightfully so. It shouldn't. Win7 is danger-old. You should _really_ consider upgrading that hardware. If it is the only hardware at your disposal, I'd personally consider making the app OS-agnostic and install Linux and the dotnet core runtime for Linux rather than downgrading the app.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods, The people can't function without Ms.Office!

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods while this is technically correct - and your advice may apply in this specific case - as a software provider, you do not always have control over the environment your clients use. From experience, this kind of situation is quite common, in particular in the public sector.

Comment: @SirDarius, CORRECT!

Comment: You don't need to downgrade to .NET Framework. .NET 6 (which is a long-term supported version as opposed to .NET 7) [supports](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/supported-os.md) Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: @sorsamele _"The people can't function without Ms.Office!"_ You did not mention that in your question. Point still stands.

Comment: @SirDarius I only partially agree. Having worked with that kind of customers, I know you _do_ have more leverage than you often might think. More than once a simple "we do not support ... " was _very warmly welcomed_ by customer's IT (if you can follow why ;) ) And guess what - nearly never did it lead to lost contracts.

Comment: Just for the record: I guess switching to a SaaS ("Software as a Service" - aka "Cloud App" or "Browser App") approach is completely off the table, right?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods,Yes